# Creating a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to change the font-size of text through a dropdown and for the most part it is working like i wanted. Although, is there a better way to do it like using a computed or watcher? Not sure how i would execute that?

this is a working pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoMXPB?editors=1011
How can i change logic on line 6 to replace it with a computed or watcher?

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container>
            <v-select :items="items" label="Font-Size" v-model="myFont">
            </v-select>
            <div>
                <p :style="{'font-size': myFont == 'Large' ? 24 + 'px' : myFont == 
     'Medium' ? 18 + 'px' : 14 + 'px'}">Large="24px", Small="16px",
                    Medium="18px"</p>
            </div>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</div>


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                'Large',
                'Medium',
                'Small',
            ],
            myFont: null,
        };
    },
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, a computed property (or in this case a method) could help you here - largely just condensing the code and making it a little more flexible;

```js
methods: {
  calculateFontSize: function(size){
   switch(size){
    case "LARGE":
      return "24px";
    case "MEDIUM":
      return "18px";
    default:
      return "14px";
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<p :style="calculateFontSize(myFont)"></p>
```

Comment: I like this way of doing(as i was trying to do something like this) but it's giving me an error message saying calculateFontSize is not a function

Comment: My bad, to use Parma like this you’re better off creating it as a method. Exactly the same code, just change computed to methods. See my updated code.

Comment: Takes away the error but the size won't change now!!

Comment: Very strange. Can I confirm the html part looks like `<p :style="'font-size:' + calculateFontSize(myFont)"></p>`?

Comment: I see what i was doing wrong. It worked. Thank you. Accepting it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

What about using an array of objects as your options to simplify the conditional in the computed property.

Note the `item-text` and `item-value` props in the v-select. Then the conditional can be used to simply add the style syntax `font-size: ${this.myFont}px`

```js
Vue.config.silent = true;
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { label: 'Large', value: 24 },
      { label: 'Medium', value: 18 },
      { label: 'Small', value: 16 },
    ],
    myFont: 16
  }),
  computed: {
    style() {
      return `font-size: ${this.myFont}px` ;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.18/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-select :items="items" item-text="label" item-value="value" label="Font-Size" v-model="myFont"></v-select>
      <div>
        <p :style="style">Font is {{myFont}}px</p>
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Could I suggest disabling the console in your snippet? Makes it difficult to see the result, even in the expanded snippet.